# R Stacked Bar Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table, melt

```
data1=data.frame("Grade"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
"Class"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
"Score"=c(6,9,9,7,7,4,9,6,6))
```

I am sincerely apologetic if this already was posted but I did not see it. I wish to prepare a stacked bar plot there the X axis is 'Grade' and each Grade is 1 bar. Every bar contains three color shades because there are three classes ('Class'). Finally the height of the bar is 'Score' and it always starts from low class to high. So it will look something like this but this is not to proper scale

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `xtabs` to convert the data to wide format and then apply the `barplot`

```
barplot(xtabs(Score ~ Grade + Class, data1), legend = TRUE,
         col = c('yellow', 'red', 'orange'))
```

---

Or using `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data1 %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(Grade, Class), factor) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = Grade, y = Score, fill = Class)) + 
          geom_col()
```

[image]

---

If we want to order for 'Class', convert to `factor` with `levels` specified in that order based on the 'Score' values

```
data1 %>% 
   mutate(Class = factor(Class, levels = unique(Class[order(Score)])), 
          Grade = factor(Grade)) %>%  
   ggplot(aes(x = Grade, y = Score, fill = Class)) + 
           geom_col()
```

Comment: thanks again and lastly how do I force the stacks to be in order of class from low to high? So class 1, class 2, class 3 instead of class 3, class 2, class 1